# Change animation-duration at any point using JS or jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a simple HTML page with a div in the center of the page and two buttons below it. The animation I want to have is the bg of the div going from black to white in a linear manner in a given duration. This duration would change according to which button I press at the bottom. Changing animation-duration/animationDuration simply with JS doesn't work, this is a known problem as far as I've seen online. I'm open to solutions using jQuery as well.

**My code:**

```js
$(".b1").click(function(){
   $("#movie").removeClass("t1");
      $("#movie").removeClass("t2");
      $("#movie").addClass("t1");
})

$(".b2").click(function(){
   $("#movie").removeClass("t1");
      $("#movie").removeClass("t2");
      $("#movie").addClass("t2");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#movie {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.t1 {
  -webkit-animation: change 1s infinite;
  animation: change 1s infinite;
}

.t2 {
  -webkit-animation: change 10s infinite;
  animation: change 10s infinite;
}

button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>    
<body>
  <div id="movie"></div>
  <button type="button" class="b1">Test 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="b2">Test 2</button>
</body>
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/taqxs13q/5/).

Comment: I had omited it (now I added it), but adding that line still doesn't help when I try this in a browser.

Comment: But I still don't get what "is not working"... Could you clarify please ? For me your solution does work : the animation-duration is updated.

Comment: What is not working is that clicking the buttons does not update the animation-duration. Did you try it as a .html file opened by a browser? It works in this "run code snippet" thing, but it disnae work as a piece of code in an .html file opened by a browser of your choosing.

Comment: So you do agree that it works in the snippet here ? If so the problem is probably logged into your developer console. (and I would suspect an '$ is not a function' or alike) but anyway it probably has nothing to do with the CSS in question. Things to check : scripts are loaded, css is loaded (if external).

Comment: @Kaiido Yes, I agree that the snippet here works, sorry for being unclear. You're double right, the error is in the console: _ReferenceError: $ is not defined_. Do you know how I fix this? CSS is internal, so it's fine. The JS is internal as well.

Comment: I would guess you're loading your html file through the `file://` protocol, and that your browers don't allow loading external scripts from this protocol. Best solution if you are planning to do web-dev is to [setup a localhost](https://www.google.com/search?q=install+localhost&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab#q=setup+localhost+server).

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".b1").click(function(){
   $("#movie").removeClass("t1");
      $("#movie").removeClass("t2");
      $("#movie").addClass("t1");
})

$(".b2").click(function(){
   $("#movie").removeClass("t1");
      $("#movie").removeClass("t2");
      $("#movie").addClass("t2");
})
```

```css
body {
  background: black;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 300px;
  height: auto;
}

#movie {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  background: red;
}

.t1 {
  -webkit-animation: change 1s infinite;
  animation: change 1s infinite;
}

.t2 {
  -webkit-animation: change 10s infinite;
  animation: change 10s infinite;
}

button {
  margin-top: 15px;
}

@keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes change {
  from {
    background-color: black;
  }
  to {
    background-color: white;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div id="movie"></div>
  <button type="button" class="b1">Test 1</button>
  <button type="button" class="b2">Test 2</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is supposed to work, yes, but it doesn't, in any browser of mine that I tried. It does work in "run code snippet" window here, though.

Comment: I've double-checked it in Firefox, Chrome, Safari, but it doesn't work outside of "run code snippet" or JSFiddle.

Comment: This answer would probably benefit of an explanation of what has been changed (I can't find it).